# Can not find generated .keystore Files

Tags: java, ssl, localhost, keystore

I Try to generate a Keystore locally, so i can use SSL-Certificate at localhost.

I am using this Tutorial:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

So it says if i do

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

in the Java Home /bin

it will create a .keystore File in my user home directory. 
I can create a file with the tool, it seems. I get asked all the questions, and if i try to redo with the same alias, it tells me it already exists. However, there are no .keystore files in my users home directory. I can not find them in the search, either. (Using Mac OS).

Can someone help me with that?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename starts with a '.' so it is a hidden file. Are you sure it isn't there?

You can list all files (including hidden ones) in Mac OS terminal with a command 'ls -a'.

Comment: Well, that was stupid.. It really was just hidden. Well anyways, if i follow the Tutorial further, my browser wont load the applications. It  does not show any error at all, just does not load the site. Worked perfectly fine with :8080. Now if i do :8080 i get redirected to :8443 but the site does not load.

Comment: Try a different browser (you might get some certificate error) and check the tomcat logs for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

Add a new keystore named “myKeys”

```
    keytool -genkey -keystore myKeys -alias jdc
```

It will ask for keystore password, first name, last name , organization’s unit…etc..just fill them all.